# How do i extract title of this webpage in python 2.7 using bs4?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, index-error

Currently i am using the code below :

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import codecs 

file_obj = open("E:\\Sport_Cricket.txt", "r+")    
links_str = file_obj.readlines()    

c=1    
for j in links_str:
 url=j.rstrip('\n')  
 if(url.endswith("ece")):
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"lxml")

    #title
    webpage_title = soup.find_all("h1", attrs = {"class": "title"}) 
    webpage_title = webpage_title[0].get_text(strip=True) 
    with codecs.open("E:\\Corpus\\Sport\\Cricket\\text"+str(c)+".txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     f.writelines(webpage_title+"\r\n")

    c=c+1
```

Sport_Cricket.txt contains :

```
http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/unadkat-does-the-trick-for-pune/article18401543.ece
http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/live-updates-delhi-daredevils-versus-mumbai-indians/article18400821.ece
http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/old-guard-wants-pull-out-coa-warns-of-consequences/article18400811.ece
http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/the-rise-of-sandeep-sharma/article18400700.ece
http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/axar-has-found-his-mojo/article18400258.ece
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\PJM\working_extractor_sorted_complete.py", line 31, in <module>
webpage_title = webpage_title[0].get_text(strip=True)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there any alternate option instead of `webpage_title = webpage_title[0].text(strip=True)`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pankaj,

Use this instead to get the title using BeautifulSoup.

```
webpage_title = soup.title.string
```

This will get the first title element anywhere in the html document.